# What is the name of the horizontal division line?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology, mathematics

What is the name of the horizontal division line? Is there a name for it other than "division line?

[image: x above a horizontal line above y]

Comment: Wikipedia article on [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Notation), the very first sentence in the very first subsection: "Division is often shown in algebra and science by placing the dividend over the divisor with a horizontal line, also called a [vinculum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_%28symbol%29) or fraction bar, between them."

Comment: This symbol is in some places referred to as a [lemnisc](http://www.textcreationpartnership.org/docs/dox/moresyms.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Vinculum** is a word used broadly to describe [any horizontal line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_%28symbol%29) in mathematical symbols. The line between numerator and denominator, the line above the recurring decimal, etc are some examples of vincula.

More commonly, the line is called a fraction or division bar.

On a related note, the '/' sign denoting division in a/b is called a **solidus** and the ÷ sign in a÷b is called an **obelus**.

Comment: Oops, I find I have repeated others' answers here. Sorry, I didn't see them when adding this answer.

Comment: Your answer may have echoed what others said, but it is arguably the best of the answers, since it offers more detailed information than the others. I for one did not know that the line above recurring decimals was also called a vinculum. (The correct plural is _vincula_, though; not *vinculi)

Answer (score 3):

The horizontal line is called a ***[vinculum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_%28symbol%29)***.

DEF: "A vinculum is a horizontal line used in mathematical notation" (Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia).

I think you'll find that the term is infrequently used and it's more likely someone would say "x over y" or "x divided by y".

Answer (score 1):

the line between the numerator and denominator is known as the **fraction bar** or **division bar**

Comment: Could you please use more of [your own words](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/9603/2085) so it’s a real answer?